# Wordpress: Scheduled category change (workflow). How to do?

Tags: php, cron, wordpress, schedule

I think it is a common case:I have three categories: Past, Current, Upcoming.

Now I write a post about next month's event. I put this post in Upcoming category.

What I want is a scheduled category change.

i.e.:

This event runs from Dec 1 to Dec 10. From now till Nov 30, this post is in Upcoming category (I select this category when creating this post).

On Dec 1, this post will be in Current category automatically, till Dec 10.

On Dec 11, this post will be in Past category automatically.

I did a search and did not find such plug-in.

Basically, I want the publishing page to have two extra options:

Option 1: Change to Category **_ on _**

Option 2: Change to Category **_ on _**

It sounds like a workflow question. I searched workflow related plugin but still with no luck.

Any suggestion on how to implement this? I can write a plugin but I am new to WP. Could anybody suggest me which API/functions to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: There could be a plugin out there that can handle what you want to achieve. If you need a simple events calendar, I am almost certain this can be done with existing plugins. Off the top of my head, [MyCalendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-calendar/) would be one such plugin. You might want to search the [wordpress plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) for further options, before you dive into coding this on your own.

That being said, if you can't avoid constructing this yourself, because you're case is to specialized, this should get you started:

Either use [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to add the extra meta-data of start and end date or make the events a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) of their own. Explaining the use of custom post types en detail is past the scope of a concise SO answer.

If you opt for the simpler way of adding two custom fields called *start* and *end* (or the like), you will have to either run a php script as a cronjob via your server or make us of the [WP-Cron Functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category%3aWP-Cron_Functions) to compare the current time with the start and end date and change the category accordingly.

To provide you with some useful code (which would go into your self-written plugin), the following php snippet should point you in the right direction:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'your_activation');
add_action('your_daily_event', 'change_categories');

function your_activation() {
    $first_time = time(); // you probably want this to be shortly after midnight
    $recurrence = 'daily';
    wp_schedule_event($first_time, $recurrence, 'your_daily_event');
}

function change_categories() {
    $old_name = 'Upcoming'; // category to delete
    $taxonomy = 'category';
    // fetch category ID (amongst other data) of 'Upcoming':
    $term = get_term_by('name',$old_name, $taxonomy);
    // fetch all posts in 'Upcoming' category:
    $objects = get_objects_in_term($term->term_id,$taxonomy);
    // the $objects array now contains the post IDs of all upcoming events

    // now, let's loop through them to manipulate:
    foreach($objects as $object) {
         // get start date:
         $key = 'start'; // the name of the custom field
         $start = get_post_meta($object, $key, true); // start date
         $todays_date = date('Y-m-d'); // get current date
         // Assuming, your dates in the custom fields are formatted YYYY-MM-DD:
         if ($start < $todays_date) {
             // change category:
             $new_name = 'Current';
             wp_set_post_terms( $object, $new_name, $taxonomy, false );
         }
    }

?>
```

Few notes:

- The above would have to be altered for the change from "Current" to "Past", obviously.
- It can easily be adapted to include time as well.
- The cronjobs should initiate shortly after midnight
- `$first_time` has to be a [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
- Check the [wordpress function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/) for more information on the wp functions used above